# How to reset state with componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm a newbie to React and I am working on a quiz. What I would like to do now is reset the classnames to it's initial state when you get a new question. I think I want to use componentDidUpdate but not really sure how it works.

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState({
      classNames: ["", "", "", ""]
    });
  }
```

Here is the full component code:

```
class Answers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAnswered: false,
      classNames: ["", "", "", ""]
    };

    this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
  }

  checkAnswer(e) {
    let { isAnswered } = this.props;

    if (!isAnswered) {
      let elem = e.currentTarget;
      let { correct, increaseScore } = this.props;
      let answer = Number(elem.dataset.id);
      let updatedClassNames = this.state.classNames;

      if (answer === correct) {
        updatedClassNames[answer - 1] = "right";
        increaseScore();
      } else {
        updatedClassNames[answer - 1] = "wrong";
      }

      this.setState({
        classNames: updatedClassNames
      });

      this.props.showButton();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState({
      classNames: ["", "", "", ""]
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { answers } = this.props;
    let { classNames } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="answers">
        <ul>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[0]} data-id="1">
            <p>{answers[0]}</p>
          </li>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[1]} data-id="2">
            <p>{answers[1]}</p>
          </li>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[2]} data-id="3">
            <p>{answers[2]}</p>
          </li>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[3]} data-id="4">
            <p>{answers[3]}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Answers;
```

Any help is appreciated! And feedback on the whole code project is also much appreciated since I am learning.

Below is a link the complete project:

https://codesandbox.io/s/another-quiz-mfmop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy fix for this (and recommended as a React best practice), if you change the `key` for the answers, working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/another-quiz-wgycs

```
<Answers
  key={question}    // <-- oh hi
  answers={answers}
  correct={correct}
  ...
```

Ideally you would use an `id`, and since most modern data structures have an id, this would make it ideal to use `key={question_id}` as the key has to be unique:

```
{
    id: 1
    question: 'What does CSS stand for?',
    answers: [...],
    correct: 3
},
{
    id: 2,
     ....
}
```

If not, you would have to use `prevProps`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.question !== prevProps.question) {
    this.setState(....)
  }
}
```

I really recommend the `key` way, as this will force the creation of a new component, in practice if you need to keep checking for changing props, it can become a bit hard to keep track.

Remember, ideally there should be an `id`, because if the question text is the same, it would lead to a nasty hard-to-find bug.

Also, instead of saving the classnames, it's better to just save `selected` as an index and choose the right classname on the render method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuan-Hao for an answer easy to understand! I will make sure to add an id also :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You have to add a button to reset the classes names and this button will call a function for resetting them like:

```js
import React from "react";

class Answers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAnswered: false,
      classNames: ["", "", "", ""]
    };
  }

  checkAnswer = e => {
    let { isAnswered } = this.props;

    if (!isAnswered) {
      let elem = e.currentTarget;
      let { correct, increaseScore } = this.props;
      let answer = Number(elem.dataset.id);
      let updatedClassNames = this.state.classNames;

      if (answer === correct) {
        updatedClassNames[answer - 1] = "right";
        increaseScore();
      } else {
        updatedClassNames[answer - 1] = "wrong";
      }

      this.setState({
        classNames: updatedClassNames
      });

      this.props.showButton();
    }
  };

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      isAnswered: false,
      classNames: ["", "", "", ""]
    });
  };
  render() {
    let { answers } = this.props;
    let { classNames } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="answers">
        <button onClick={this.reset}>RESET</button>
        <ul>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[0]} data-id="1">
            <p>{answers[0]}</p>
          </li>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[1]} data-id="2">
            <p>{answers[1]}</p>
          </li>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[2]} data-id="3">
            <p>{answers[2]}</p>
          </li>
          <li onClick={this.checkAnswer} className={classNames[3]} data-id="4">
            <p>{answers[3]}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Answers;
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
I have face this kind of scenario recently. you have to the same code in `componentDidUpdate() {}`. Here is what I did.

```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.questions !== prevProps.questions) {
          const shuffledAnswerOptions = this.props.questions.map(question =>
          question.answer_options && 
            this.shuffleArray(question.answer_options)
          );

           this.setState({
              current_question:this.props.questions && 
               this.props.questions[0],
               question_image_url: this.props.questions && 
               this.props.questions[0] && 
             this.props.questions[0].question_image_url,
           answerOptions: shuffledAnswerOptions[0],
         numberOfQuestions: this.props.questions && 
          this.props.questions.length
          });
       }
     }
```

In your case you `prevSate` parameter as well.

here is a sample implementation:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if(this.state.assignment !== prevState.assignment){
        document.getElementById(prevState.assignment.id) && document.getElementById(prevState.assignment.id).classList.remove("headactiveperf");
      }
      if(this.state.assessment !== prevState.assessment){
        document.getElementById(prevState.assessment.id) && document.getElementById(prevState.assessment.id).classList.remove("headactiveperf");
      }
      if(this.state.study_group_id !== prevState.study_group_id){
        document.getElementById(prevState.study_group_id) && document.getElementById(prevState.study_group_id).classList.remove("klassactiveperf");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that if you change state in `componentDidUpdate` it will trigger another update right away and therefore run `componentDidUpdate` again and result in an infinite loop. So you should either move the `setState` somewhere else, or put it behind a condition. e.g.:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (!this.state.classNames.every(className => className === "") { // Check if there is an item in the array which doesn't match an empty string ("")
    this.setState({ // Only update state if it's necessary
      classNames: ["", "", "", ""]
    });
  }
}
```

You can find an updated CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/another-quiz-fb2fl)